# joining 3 tables in one sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables as described below ,

```
table1 'ads'

 id     userid
 1       47
 2       47                    //ads.id  = adcat.adid
 3       45
 4       47

table2  'adcat'

  adid    catid
   1        1
   2        3
   3        3                 // adcat.catid  = categories.id
   4        3

 table3  'categories'

   id        name
    1        mathematic
    2        biolog
    3        leteratur
    4        chemi
```

What I want is to get `categories.id` from `ads.id`.

I have tried this

```
SELECT categories.id, ads.id 
FROM ads 
INNER JOIN adcat ON ads.id = adcat.adid 
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = adcat.catid
```

But it does not come by the exact value.

obs : I don't get any error just not exact value.
any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: what result do you want to get? It seems that you have correct `join` syntax.

Comment: Your result will be same as adcat table with different colum order. What is the result you see when you execute that sql statement?

Comment: i have ads.id  and i want get from it the categories.id

Comment: the result is i get other ids , other numbers which does not exist

Comment: If you only want categories.id then you could just use adcat.catid and skip the second join since they are the same number. Is there more you need from categories?

Comment: Can you edit your post to show what the table of results you want would actually look like, like you did for your current 3 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be no reason to go in to categories table if adcat.catid = categories.id and that is the only value you need.

```
SELECT ads.id,adcat.catid
FROM ads
INNER JOIN adcat
ON ads.id=adcat.adid
```

Use `$row['catid']` with this query.

If in the future you need more columns from categories then you will need a double join:

```
SELECT categories.id *AS id*,ads.id *AS ads_id*
FROM ads 
INNER JOIN adcat ON ads.id = adcat.adid  
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = adcat.catid
```

Use `$row['id']` with this query.

See `*AS id*` and `*AS ads_id*` - remove the stars and you are giving the columns an `ALIAS` which is basically like a nickname, this can be handy in many cases but especially important in this case since the two columns both have the same names. So now you can call `$row['id']` and get categories.id

Comment: catid.id ?? you maybe done wrong here , i dont know what u mean

Comment: Got mixed up with your table and column names, but I edited it a few mins ago. But if you want us to provide you with an accurate answer the best thing you can do is show the table result you are actually aiming for.

Comment: i get same result as before, maybe its me who is echoing wrong , im echoing like that  `$row['id']` is it right?

Comment: That would give you ads.id not adcat.catid or categories.id. You need to do `$row['catid']` for my example, which since it skips out an unnecessary join seems most sensible, but if in the future you need more columns from categories then switch over to the double joins.

Comment: I will edit my answer to clarify what to do with the double joins.

Comment: In the future you can try `print_r($row)` to see what information is in your query result array, which will also show you the column names that you should be using.

Comment: it does not give any result :(

Comment: what doesn't give any result? `print_r($row)` or `$row['catid']`? Make sure to use `$row['catid']` with my query and `$row['id']` with the double join but removing the stars. Does `print_r($row)` show anything for either query? You could post a snippet of what it displays on your question. I updated my post since I posted the triple from rather then the double join, I'd personally use the double join.

Comment: `$row['catid']` displays nothing in ur query , and  `$row['catid']` displays wrong category id

Comment: i try your first or second sql ? there is 2

Comment: First one, and if you don't get the result you want then use `print_r($row)` and paste the result here.

Comment: hehehehe waw it works :) i get exact value :) , i know u was sure about it :) thanks genious :)

Comment: Great, we finally got there. Good luck with the rest of it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly is the question but I think you are trying to get not all but single row based on one ads.id if so:

```
SELECT categories.id ,ads.id 
FROM ads 
INNER JOIN adcat ON ads.id = adcat.adid  
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = adcat.catid
WHERE ads.id = your_id_here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT categories.id, ads.id 
FROM ads, adscat, categories
WHERE ads.id=adcat.adid
AND categories.id = adcat.catid
```